# Is there a wave function in loop quantum gravity?

Tags: wavefunction, quantum-gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

In the postulates of quantum mechanics, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html
a wavefunction is fundamental.

Is there a wavefunction - or an analogon - in loop quantum gravity?

As the theory constructs background-independent the space itself from scratch, I cannot imagine how a wavefunction (which is dependent on position and time) may unfold in this view.

Answer (score 1):

The wavefunction, in the sense of a complex-valued function of space and time, is not really that fundamental in quantum mechanics, beyond the case of a single quantum mechanical particle without spin. In the Schrodinger picture, the wavefunction $\Psi(x, t)$, is the quantum state $|\Psi(t)\rangle$ projected onto a basis consisting of the position of a single particle, $|x\rangle$:
\begin{equation}
\Psi(x, t) = \langle x | \Psi(t)\rangle
\end{equation}
If you have $N$ particles, then one valid set of basis states will give you the position of each particle, $|x_1, x_2, \cdots x_N\rangle$, so the generalization of $\Psi(x, t)$ to the multi-particle case is a function from $N$ coordinates to a complex number, that evolves in time in the Schrodinger picture
\begin{equation}
\Psi(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N, t) = \langle x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N | \Psi(t)\rangle
\end{equation}
There is no need for the basis states to be labeled by position, and therefore no need for the "wavefunction" to be a function of position variables at all. They could label spin polarization states, for example. Or, you could work in the momentum basis.

I am not an expert in Loop Quantum Gravity, so I can't give a definitive answer. As I understand, the basic variables of LQG are things like the area and volume of some basic geometric objects. There is no problem, from the point of view of quantum mechanics, of having the basis states labeled by the area, volume, or whatever, of some set of degrees of freedom, that do not have a position space representation.

As for the time dependence, this is a general conceptual problem with any quantum theory of gravity; see [1, 2].

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_time

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93DeWitt_equation#Hamiltonian_constraint